# How to use JSDoc to document an ES6 class property

Tags: jsdoc, es6-class

I'm using the [`documentation` package](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation), but cannot figure out how to get it to document class properties (that aren't defined via getters and setters).

As the following just generates class documentation for SomeClass, but omits the someProperty documentation.

```js
/**
 * SomeClass is an example class for my question.
 * @class
 * @constructor
 * @public
 */
class SomeClass {
    constructor () {
        this.someProperty = true  // how do I document this?
    }

    /**
     * someProperty is an example property that is set to `true`
     * @property {boolean} someProperty
     * @public
     */
}
```

An aside: the `@constructor` on the class jsdoc is a [`documentation` thing](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation/issues/1091).

Comment: Does [`@instance`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-instance.html) work?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, or at least from my attempt.

Comment: You don't need the `@class` since JSDoc already knows that it is a class.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Move the JSDoc for `someProperty` into the constructor where it is first defined:

```js
/**
 * SomeClass is an example class for my question.
 * @class
 * @constructor
 * @public
 */
class SomeClass {
    constructor () {
        /**
         * someProperty is an example property that is set to `true`
         * @type {boolean}
         * @public
         */
        this.someProperty = true
    }
}
```

I'm unsure if there is a way of accomplishing it with the [`documentation` package](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation) using an approach that doesn't involve inlining the JSDocs into the constructor.

Comment: What if `SomeClass` extends another class, which defines `someProperty` as `any`?

Answer (score 15):

Another way is to declare them in class documentation as follows:

```js
/**
 * Class definition
 * @property {type} propName - propriety description
 * ...
 */
class ClassName {
  constructor () {...}
  ...
}
```

Comment: This did not work with VSCode intellisense for me, but balupton's solution did.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 (16.10) also doesn't support this syntax. Would be nice if it did, but until then, you just have to mix the JSDoc info inline with the property definitions.

Comment: After i updated something in my vs code, this stopped working, i suggest moving to typescript in order to have a nice working intellisense.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare properties in a class, and use @type to declare a type for them. Worked in VSCode 1.70.2 with in a plain ECMAScript Module.

```js
class Foo {
   /** 
    * Some bary data
    * @type { BarClass }
    */
   bar;
}

let f = new Foo();
f.bar;    // Intellisense can tell you type and purpose
```

Comment: This work for me especially with class that come from Node packages. Example: `@type {Promise<mariadb.Connection>} #conn` for use with **madiadb** package.