# JSDoc not hinting class properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellisense, ecmascript-5, jsdoc

I have a simple class `User` and I am using ES5:

```
/**
 * @property {number} id
 * @property {string} username
 * @property {string} password
 * @property {string} email
 */
class User {
  
  constructor(obj) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However I cannot get VSCode's intellisense to hint any of the instance properties if I type say:

```
let a = new User();
a.|      <-- Here intellisense should hint me id, username, etc...
```

Intellisense will only hint properties if I explicitly declare them in the constructor like so:

```
constructor(obj) {
    this.id = 1;
    this.username = '';
}
```

How can I write the JSDoc in the correct form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JSDoc to document an ES6 class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467835/how-to-use-jsdoc-to-document-an-es6-class-property) - you may also want to move your jsdoc to markup the constructor instead of the class.

Comment: I have also tried that. It seems that properties are not hinting unless I assign the variables in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
class User {
  /** @type {number} */
  id
  /** @type {string} */
  username
  /** @type {string} */
  password
  /** @type {string} */
  email

  constructor(obj) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]